# Moodle Course Renderer Hidden Topics

Tags: php, mysql, moodle

I'm trying to show a graphic if a topic/section within a course has access restricted by an Activity completion condition and is shown greyed-out with restriction information.

I've had limited success, within the course renderer function `section_left_content` I have tried using `$thismod->available` and `$section->showavailability` to check whether the topic is restricted, both work for admin users, however both variables are null for students therefore the check fails.

Is there a better way to do this? It feels like a *role permission issue*.

Using Moodle v2.5.2, Topics course format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at this line:
https://github.com/moodle/moodle/blob/MOODLE_25_STABLE/course/format/renderer.php#L738

This is the example of how to check section availability, you can override the course renderer in your own theme to avoid hacking core code.